# Compare data and insert row for unmatched on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have a list of account numbers on one sheet (Balances) and another list of account numbers on another sheet (Todays Bals).  I want to compare those 2 sheets to find out if there are any new account numbers on Todays Bals and if there are I need to Insert a Row at the bottom of an ever growing list (so no set range) of account numbers on the Balances sheet and only copy over the account number into the inserted row in column A.

I found the below code while googling and this takes me up to the point of finding the unmatched numbers and filtering it within the Todays Bals sheet (actually makes a 2nd Todays Bals sheet).  I now need to Insert the same amount of rows in the Balances sheet (so say the filter found 2 unmatched, I want to insert 2 new rows in Balances).  And then copy only the account numbers to the first cell in the newly inserted rows.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Todays Bals")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Balances")

ws1.Copy after:=ws2
Set ws3 = wb.ActiveSheet

With ws3
    LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D1").Value = "Vlookup"
    .Range("D2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & ws2.Name & "!A:A,1,0)"
    .Range("D2").Copy .Range("D3:D" & LastRow1)
    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0)
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, 4)
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsToday As Worksheet, wsBalances As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, r As Long, arr, v
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsToday = wb.Worksheets("Todays Bals")
    Set wsBalances = wb.Worksheets("Balances")
    
    lr = wsToday.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    arr = wsToday.Range("A1:A" & lr).Value 'get all today's values as an array
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'loop over the array
        v = arr(r, 1)           'value to check
        If Len(v) > 0 Then      'not zero-length
            'doesn't already exist in Balances sheet?
            If IsError(Application.Match(v, wsBalances.Columns(1), 0)) Then
                'copy over the new value
                wsBalances.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = v
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  I've tested it and it does what I need up to the last line (wsBalances.Cells...).  This is just adding the missing account number to the bottom of the Balances sheet, but I need to have a new Row inserted at the bottom of the Balances sheet and then the missing number put in the first cell of the row (in column A).  There are totals at the bottom of the sheet which is why a new row is needed.

Comment: After the new row and missing number has been added to Balances, I will have another problem.  The Balances sheet has the daily balance of each account going across (so each account has balances for each day on one row).  I'll need to auto-populate the new row with N/A up to the day the last balances were added (so the next cell in the row has nothing above it until the header in row 1 (which is a date - the dates have been pre-populated as headers across row 1).

Comment: Is the data on Balances in a Table/ListObject?

Comment: I did create a Table/ListObject name Accounts that covers the whole of the list in Balances, but haven't actually used it in any of the coding so far.

Comment: I amended some of your code slightly within the If statement and it now works as I expect it to.  Your code was a great help for me.

Comment: In that case please flag as "Accepted" so others can see there's a working solution.